# How to detect in runtime if some Compiler Option (like Optimization) is on?

Tags: delphi, runtime, delphi-7, conditional-compilation

I would like to show in the Caption of the program how was the program complied. Most important, I would like to show if the Compiler Optimization is on/off.

(Range Checking and other stuff like this would be interesting to show also, but mainly I am interested in Compiler Optimization).

Any idea how to do it?

---

Ready to use function based on Arioch answer:

```
function CompilerOptimization: Boolean;  { Importan note: $O+ has a local scope, therefore, the result of the function reflects only the optimization state at that specific source code location. }
begin
 {$IfOpt O+}
 Result:= TRUE;
 {$Else}
 Result:= FALSE;
 {$EndIf}
end;

function CompilerOptimizationS: String;
begin
 Result:= 'Compiler optimization is ' +
 {$IfOpt O+}
 'enabled'
 {$Else}
 'disabled'
 {$EndIf}
end;
```

---

IMPORTANT: If you are using the {$O} switch to optimize pieces of code then it MUST be used as a subfunction like this, otherwise, if you use the global switch only (in Project Options) it can be used as a normal (declared) function.

```
// {$O+} or {$O-}
procedure TFrmTest.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

 function CompilerOptimizationS: String;
 begin
  Result:= 'Compiler optimization is ' +
  {$IfOpt O+}
  'enabled'
  {$Else}
  'disabled'
  {$EndIf}
 end;

begin
 ///...more code here
 Caption:= 'Version: '+ GerVerStr+ ' '+ CompilerOptimizationS+ etc+ etc;
end;
```

Comment: >"at THE DECLARATION site"  ----   I know. This is why I haven't posted the declaration in my 'ready to copy/paste' code and I added gammatester's comment. Anyway, for ME it is fine because I prefer to use the global switch (in project options) to turn on/off compiler optimization.

Comment: `{$O+} ShowMessage(CompilerOptimizationS()); {$O-} ShowMessage(CompilerOptimizationS());` - same output, once obviously not what expected. Hence CompilerOptimization better be a CONSTANT - you would not expect the constant different in different places, but you would expect it different when it is function. Or confuse you future readers , if you and me

Comment: Caveat Emptor. You always may change $O+ at exactly the call site and fool the function (and yourself) even if it is nested. So i am - for sake of self-documenting code - to use const instead. But up to you.

Comment: Yes, but I already specified that "I prefer to use the global switch (in project options) to turn on/off compiler optimization". Anyway, the idea is NOT to trick other readers. I HOPE that the edited question explains everything.

Comment: It is a duplicate. But that doesn't make it a bad question. Marking as a duplicate links the two questions together and that makes the semantic association stronger. That will help future visitors. They can land at one and be taken to the other. It is a positive.

Comment: @Arioch'The @ david - Totally agree it is a duplicate. I hope that the edited version keeps the reader warned by explaining the '{O+} is local' trap and because of this I cleaned up some of my comments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan pity that the link is unidirectional. In bug trackers when you establish a link it is reflected in both tickets...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ShowMessage(' Optimization is ' +
{$IfOpt O+}
'enabled'
{$Else}
'disabled'
{$EndIf}
);
```

PS. Documentation... Going Google for "Delphi IfOpt" will bring you a lot of links, including

- [http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=$IfOpt](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=%24IfOpt)
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IFOPT_directive_(Delphi)

PPS. *gammatester* is absolutely correct that "Since {$O+} has a *local scope*, your message/caption reflects only the optimization state at that specific source code location"

Comment: It's [`$IFOPT`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/IFOPT_directive_(Delphi)), not `$IfOpt`.

Comment: @Altar with due respect, you ought to know how to find the docs yourself. Type docwiki delphi ifopt into google.

Comment: compiler directives in delphi are case insensitive

Comment: @Arioch, I prefer how it is defined because it is defined that way. If it were in lower case, I would write it that way. You know, there are people who write code and there are people who squirt code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan maybe he wanted to quote help for Delphi 7 but i don't think it is published online. It is pity that EMBT has no table when which directive was introduced. I *think*  this directive was already in D7 but cannot ensure this.

Comment: I just made a test in Delphi XE Pro: $IfOpt works!! So, it is not case sensitive.

Comment: IFOPT has been around since forever. A doc link to today's docs is fine. My comment was mainly directed to Altar to teach the trick to locate Delphi docs. The answer at the dupe has a link to docs I note.....

Comment: 1) You write code once, you read it 10 times and your fellows would read it 100 times. 2) no matter how it was defined or declared, your claim that in Delphi "IFOPT" and "IfOpt" are different identifiers is just plainly wrong.

Comment: Since {$O+} has a **local** scope, your message/caption reflects only the optimization state at that specific source code location.

Comment: @Arioch, my point was in the used case. If you got it different, then I'm sorry. And, I don't want to discuss that anymore. Squirt your code however you want ;-)

Comment: @TLama and my point is that in Delphi sources using upcase and locase only have meaning for ease of reading. So sorry, i cannot see that comment of yours other than nitpicking. Sorry for harsh reaction.

Comment: Oh, come on... you bookmarked the link? Are you seeking revenge? That would be childish. I have nothing against you. I looked in that post and I see I gave +1 to your answer. But that post is dated 2011. I totally forgot about that post. I move on. I don't keep grudges for years.